Honda Civic 2006: Belt Tensioner Bolt Loose, but Seized to the Tensioner
Most people strip or break this bolt. I was lucky. It came off the block very easily. But I have a different problem. It's stuck to the tensioner assembly and won't come off it. That means it's creating obstruction in pulling out the tensioner out. How do I get this bolt off?

If you can edit your question and add photos, you'll find it's easier to get an answer.

While not ideal, I'd suggest you try re-threading the bolt into the hole about 1/2 way, then gently tapping the tensioner with a hammer to break the two apart. I wouldn't hit it too hard, but you might work the tensioner free of the bolt. You don't want to hit it too hard because you could possibly end up damaging the threaded hole. You might want to put some penetrant on the bolt to see if that'd help lossen it up from the tensioner. You just have to break the bond between the two, then you should be golden.

Thank you. I did both of things and was able to get the bolt out of the tensioner. After that the tensioner came off easily. Putting the new one in proved to be another nightmare though. The fit was very tight and I considered removing the water pump just to get the tensioner on. But didn't have to resort to that. Hondas are incredibly difficult to work with.

@cryptic0 - Not nearly as difficult as a Volvo I worked on here a while back, lol :o) Glad you were able to get the bolt out.
